# Flutter Flame Dropped On

Tags: flutter, drag-and-drop, flame

Using Flutter with Flame and trying to determine what Component is dropped on during a drag operation. For example, dragging a SpriteComponent works great but when I drop the component I can't seem to find any event or way of determining what component was dropped on.  Right now I keep a List of all Components placed in the game and iterate through this list to find the closest component comparing the x and Y values with the Dropped x and Y .  This is  not as accurate as I need and I'm looking for a better way of accomplishing this.  Flutter itself has the DragTarget widget but I don't believe we can use that in Flame.

Anyone have a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use collision detection for that, and make sure that your hitboxes are set to `isSolid = true` if your component can be dropped fully enclosed by another component.

Meanwhile the component is being dragged you can set the hitboxes `collisionType` to `CollisionType.inactive` so that it doesn't react to collisions, and then on the end event your set it to active again.